# Add event on html5 video play button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I only want to access the play button of the video controls, no action when pressing the track bar or volume. I want something like this but with html5 video http://flash.flowplayer.org/demos/installation/multiple-players.html

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $('.vids').click(function(){
        $('.vids').each(function () {
            this.pause();
        });
    });
});

<video controls="controls" class="vids" id="1">
   <source src ....>
</video>
<video controls="controls" class="vids" id="2">
   <source src ....>
</video>
....
```

So now all videos stop except the one I clicked but when I press the trackbar or volume, it also stops. Any solutions without making my own controls or making use of another videoplayer? I found different solutions but not as I want :S

Comment: `jQuery(document).ready(function() {` - you should either use `jQuery(document).ready(function($) {` or `$(document).ready(function() {`. But the way you did it writing `jQuery` provides no advantage whatsover.

Comment: thx, normally I use $(document)... I wrote this in a hurry :)
if it works with or without jquery or with moodle, or some other, that doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to target the current item which you are clicking so that the clicked target get the command to process to do this try this one and see if this works for you:

> ```
> $('.box').click(function(e){
>     $(e.target).pause();
> });
> ```

Comment: thx for your reply but I don't have a .box field or something, i'm using the standard controls of the HTML5 Video, and my real question is can I access the 'standard' controls in a separate manner. <br /> Think that the only solution is just writing my own controls for the videos.

Comment: You are right! There is nothing to access in the video control so better would be to write some customized controls. may be this link will help you. http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_video_js_prop

Comment: Thx for a conclusive answer, that's all I needed to hear! They should have mentioned that somewhere, even if they found it obvious. I was still hoping it was possible with some simple code, maybe future.